# How to delay re-delivery message?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using the asynchronous pull of `Cloud Pub/Sub`

For now, when I call `message.nack()` method, it will re-delievery this message immediately.

```js
subscription.on('message', (message) => {
  message.nack();
})
```

How to delay the re-delivery?

For example, I got a message with `publishTime: '2019-05-28T10:24:31.055Z'`

I want to let this message re-delivery 20 seconds(computed) later from last delivery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the message doesn't to be redelivered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353296/why-the-message-doesnt-to-be-redelivered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way in Cloud Pub/Sub to delay the redelivery of a message. When a message is nacked, it is immediately a candidate for redelivery to the same subscriber or to another subscdriber.

Comment: How about `await sleep(duration); message.nack();`? Let the application process sleep for a duration then call `message.nack()`

Comment: While this will potentially delay the message, it means that the message will still count against flow control limits. Therefore, if enough messages are in this state, then it is possible no new messages will be able to be processed until the outstanding ones are nacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can now configure a retry policy in your Cloud Pub/Sub subscription. Retry policy allows users to have per message exponential backoff in case of failures.

More information can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin).

Answer (score 0):

- Pubsub guarantee at least one time delivery.
- So unless you are not acknowledging the message, it will redeliver the
  infinite time.
- It expect to acknowledge message to complete in time which specified in
  subscription setting(Acknowledgement deadline)

**you can delay it by few setting in subscription**

1. Change **Acknowledgement deadline** to 600seconds(10 Minutes)
2. **Enable exactly one delivery** (It will make sure once ur deadline time exceed then it will do reattempt for delivery message)
3. **Enable dead Lettering**(Create topic and after 5 attempts send to new topic.)

[image]