# Why the message doesn't to be redelivered?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

The Acknowledgment Deadline is 10 seconds. When I use asynchronous-pull way to process the message, I don't call `message.ack()` and `message.nack()`, wait for the message ack deadline and expect `Pub/Sub` redeliver this message.

After waiting over 10 seconds, the subscriber doesn't receive the message again. Here is my code:

`subscriber`:

```js
import { pubsubClient, IMessage, parseMessageData } from '../../googlePubsub';
import { logger } from '../../utils';

const topicName = 'asynchronous-pull-test';
const subName = 'asynchronous-pull-test';
const subscription = pubsubClient.topic(topicName).subscription(subName);
const onMessage = (message: IMessage) => {
  const { data, ...rest } = message;
  const jsonData = parseMessageData(data);
  logger.debug('received message', { arguments: { ...rest, data: jsonData } });

  const publishTime = new Date(message.publishTime).getTime();
  const republishTimestamp = Date.now() - 5 * 1000;

  if (publishTime < republishTimestamp) {
    logger.info('message acked');
    message.ack();
  } else {
    logger.info('push message back to MQ');
  }
};
logger.info('subscribe the MQ');
subscription.on('message', onMessage).on('error', (err: Error) => logger.error(err));
```

`publisher`:

```js
const topicName = 'asynchronous-pull-test';

async function main() {
  const messagePayload = { email: faker.internet.email(), campaignId: '1' };
  await pub(topicName, messagePayload);
}

main();
```

I am using `"@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.19.0",`

I expect the subscriber will receive the message again at the ack deadline 10 seconds later. Which means my subscriber receives and processes the message every 10 seconds. Am I wrong?

Comment: Use the CLI to see if a message is still there `gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull asynchronous-pull-test`. To ack a message with gcloud add `--auto-ack`. I cannot find documentation that describes how often a message will be re-delivered. For testing you can also push messages onto your topic. This should trigger your code again. `gcloud pubsub topics publish asynchronous-pull-test --message "Hello world"`

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud Pub/Sub client libraries automatically call [`modifyAckDeadline`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/modifyAckDeadline) for messages that are neither acked or nacked for a configurable period of time. In node.js, this is configured via the [`maxExtension`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/6ef62604d5693839303acea9c31659afe4ea690b/src/lease-manager.ts#L44) property:

```
const options = {
  flowControl: {
    maxExtension: 60, // Specified in seconds
  },
};

const subscription = pubsubClient.topic(topicName).subscription(subName, options);
```

In general, it is not a good practice to not ack/nack a message as a means to delay its redelivery. This will result in the message still counting against the [flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#message-flow-control) max outstanding messages, meaning it could prevent the delivery of future messages until the originally received messages are acked or nacked. At this time, Cloud Pub/Sub does not have a means by which to delay message redelivery, but it is something under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You should nack the message to tell Pub/Sub to redeliver it. [Documentation](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pubsub/subscriber/#explaining-ack)

Comment: call `message.nack()` can tell `Pub/Sub` to redeliver it. But my subscriber message handler will received the message immediately. This is too fast because it's not the time to `ack` the message. As you can see, the message should acked 5 seconds later.  I want to `Pub/Sub` redeliver it maybe 5 seconds later. Is it possible?

Comment: IMHO, I don't think this is possible. You can't control when Pub/Sub will redeliver the message after the ackdeadline expires. It's also not a guarantee that the message will not be redelivered within the ackDeadline, documentation states "on a best-effort basis" https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions